# How can i pass authentication while using ssh client at Xcode?

Tags: xcode, shell, authentication, raspberry-pi

i want to send commands to my raspberry pi via ssh from iPhone app. I am using `system` function. However i don't know how to pass password authentication.

```
system("ssh pi@192.168.1.xx");
```

and after that authentication i want to resume that shell session.

I appreciate all helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pass password as param for ssh, but you can configure login by secure key (search keyword: ssh key authentication) for your device and use it from iphone, this way also bit more secure.

Comment: as i understand from your answer i should generate a public key from my iPhone and add that public key to my raspberry pi. if is that true how can i generate a public key from my iPhone?

Comment: I think, you should use OpenSSH from Cydia